# Unexpected behaviour while edting content in HTML text area with special charecters

Tags: html, special-characters

Hi I am facing problem in handling special charecters  inside 
text area.

```
<textarea name="comments" value="$!comments" rows="4" cols="35">
$!comments
</textarea>
```

In a page where the text are takes input had given
as

```
o!@#$%^&*()_+=//\""':;<>,./?}{[]"?
```

when I navigate to same page for edit the
Text area should show the added text but it is showing some appended
tag information as

```
<>,./?}{[]"?." rows="4" cols="35" >o!@#$%^&*()_+=//\""':;<>,./?}{[]"?.
```

There is no reason for adding these special charecters except found in testing and so 
should be fixed.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser sees this:

```
value=">,./?}{[]"?
```

and closes your `textarea` tag at `value`, then inserts the rest of the string.

If you want angle brackets  < >  you have to define HTML entities for them with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.  Otherwise, the browser will thing "end of tag" and output the error you see above.